# How to format dates and times in the form of "2 hours before"?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to format dates and times in the form of "5 hours before", just like the Calendar app does. And I also want the fomatted string be localized for many languages.

[image]

There is a new API called `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` introduced in iOS 13. However, this API can only produce localized string like "2 hours ago" and "in 2 hours". This is not suitable for my purpose.

I wonder if there is an API that provides the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think you can. This is not a common use case, and it would be crazy for there to be an API that localises every system text.

Comment: I have no idea if there is an API but the screenshoot above is properly localised on my Swedish iPhone.

Comment: Calendar app is a system app and it has localization for all languages, that does not mean the localization is provided by Foundation.

Comment: By the way, this is not relative time. Relative time would be "2 hours ago". This tells us that the notification should be "2 hours before (the event)". Therefore it's probably custom localization for all languages. The actual value is stored as `TimeInterval` in `EKAlarm.relativeOffset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested how Apple does it, the localization is available in EventKitUI framework.

```
import EventKitUI

...

let bundle = EventKitUIBundle()!

// access the string that adds "before" information to an interval
let beforeKey = bundle.localizedString(forKey: "%@ before", value: nil, table: nil)
// access the string that localizes some interval (days, in this case)
let intervalKey = bundle.localizedString(forKey: "interval_days_long", value: nil, table: nil)

// use the strings with a value
print(String(format: beforeKey, String(format: intervalKey, 1))) // 1 day before
print(String(format: beforeKey, String(format: intervalKey, 3))) // 3 days before
```

The localization dictionary contains proper pluralization for number values 1-9.
You can do exactly the same. I don't recommend using Apple's localization strings since these are not documented.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to localized the *before* part, maybe consider using `DateComponentsFormatter`?

(Maybe this is more suitable as a comment, but seems to be too long)

For example:

```
let componentsList = [
    DateComponents(minute:5),
    DateComponents(minute:10),
    DateComponents(minute:15),
    DateComponents(minute:30),
    DateComponents(hour:1),
    DateComponents(hour:2),
    DateComponents(day:1),
    DateComponents(day:2),
    DateComponents(weekOfMonth:1)
]

for components in componentsList {
    if let text = DateComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: components, unitsStyle: .full) {
        print("\(text) before")
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work only for English. Other languages will still need separate strings for every case for proper declination.

Comment: Usually App will contain other text other than this, so I was assuming there is already localization string files, and you can use a localize string with parameter, eg. `"%@ before"` for English, you just have to handle other languages yourself (which you need to do for other parts anyway).

Comment: As I said, a single string won't work for this use case. Many languages have *grammatical cases* and `DateComponentsFormatter` won't return the string in the correct grammatical case. That's why this is not useful. Sorry, I wanted to say *declension*, not *declination*. For example, in my language "2 hours" would be localized as "2 hodiny" but the proper relative string would be "před 2 hodinami".

Comment: To be honest, this would probably work for most cases but Apple obviously uses localized strings for every interval type with pluralization patterns for different numbers.